# powershell google sheets restmethod post

Tags: powershell, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a powershell script to get information from a google sheet, change data and then update the info in the google sheet. I have it working were i can get the data, but i'm having a issues posting the data back. Right now im only requesting one row as of now. it comes back as a array of array object in $file. To change the data i do $file[0][2]. This will change the data in column two to what ever i want.

What does the body need to look like? i have tried different things but keep getting a bad request error. My message body looks like this;

```
$body = @{
           "values" = $File
}
```

EDIT: So i guess use you need to add the "?valueInputOption=RAW" to the end of the URL. So i'm able to change the data, but i still cant use a array to update the whole row. What is the best way to update the  whole row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) to update values in a spreadsheet. Check the [Writing guide docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing) for more info and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to convert the data you return to JSON format? Most API's (as far as i've seen them) mostly like there data back in JSON.

try this:

```
$data = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

and return `$data` to google sheets.

i might be wrong but have only done this a few times too.